# Is there a way to concatenate matlab arrays with python (e.g. using scipy.io)?

Tags: python, matlab, mat-file

I'm trying to write a large (~ 20GB) .fvp file, which behaves like a delimited text file to a matlab array and save it as a .mat with python 3. Right now, I am reading the file in python, converting the values to a single numpy array and saving it with `scipy.io.savemat()`.

However, my pc runs out of memory in the process, which I think is due to the large size of the numpy array since my code runs okay for smaller .fvp files.

To solve this problem, I want to write and save sections of the .fvp file in multiple .mat files and join them up later, preferably in python. Is there a way to do it? I can't find it in scipy.io.

Comment: Do you mean join the MAT-files on disk? How would that work? In MATLAB you can write to a MAT-file incrementally. I would recommend that route. If you use Python only, why use MAT-files?

Comment: I don't have MATLAB on my current computer and writing the .mat files takes a long time. So to save time I was thinking of writing the .mat files with python on this computer and then transferring them to a faculty computer that does have MATLAB installed for analysis. My idea was to write `mat1.mat`, `mat2.mat` ... and join them together with python if possible.

Comment: Why not keep the files with partial matrices and concatenate them in MATLAB on the faculty machine, which I presume has more memory than yours?

Comment: I was hoping to keep things compartmentalised, by preparing one .mat file on one computer and running the analysis on the faculty machine. I suppose I'll follow your suggestion if there's no way to do it. Thanks!